# Why does var c = "a" || "b" return c = "a" and var c = "a" && "b" return c = "b"?

Tags: javascript, logic, operators

I was recently presented with this question `var c = "a" || "b"` then what is `c`, and `var c = "a" && "b"` what is `c` in this case? And explain why?

I tried running the code in jsfiddle this is what I got `var c = "a" || "b"` returns c = "a" and `var c = "a" && "b"` returns c = b. Can anyone explain why it is like that?

Comment: "can anyone explain why it is so". Yes, because the spec says so. The internet has so many contents regarding JavaScript operators. This is JavaScript 101. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: @vohuman thanks for the resource

Answer (score 3):

For an OR `||` operator any one of the condition needs to be `true`, since first one `"a"` doesn't amount to `false`, so the first value is assigned to `c`.

For an AND `&&` operator both conditions needs to be `true`, so after checking last condition (and both doesn't amound to `false`) `b` is assigned to `c`

similarly

```
var c = "a" && "b" && "d"
```

will output `"d"`

and

```
var c = false || "a" || "b"
```

will output `"a"`

Answer (score 1):

Run this snippet and it will demonstrate that && returns the right side of the expression, and || returns the left side of the express if it is defined. If the left side of a || expression is not defined, it used the right side as a default value.

```js
function ampAmp(target, a, b) {
  target.innerText = a && b;
}

function barBar(target, a) {
  target.innerText = a || "defaultValue";
}

ampAmp(document.getElementById("ampAmp1"), 1, 2);

ampAmp(document.getElementById("ampAmp2"), 2);

barBar(document.getElementById("barBar1"));

barBar(document.getElementById("barBar2"), 1);
```

```html
<p> ampAmp1 returns: 
  <span id="ampAmp1"></span>
</p>

<p> ampAmp2 returns: 
  <span id="ampAmp2"></span>
</p>

<p> barBar1 returns: 
  <span id="barBar1"></span>
</p>

<p> barBar2 returns: 
  <span id="barBar2"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that when the || operator is reached, the script looks no further having found that "a" is non-zero. Whereas with the && operator, both expressions must be evaluated to establish the truth of the statement.